# Не запускается дистрибутив Pop!_OS, после попытки обновления драйвера nVidia

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, обновление, запуск

Я решил начинать переходить на Линукс, и мой друг посоветовал мне Pop!_OS, что, как я понял, почти копия Ubuntu. Мы с ним день провозились с настройкой дистрибутива, поставили Cinnamon, всё оформили, начали скачивать программы, но день кончился, и я продолжил всё устанавливать у себя дома. В результате узнал, что есть кс го под линукс. Я его установил, но он что-то лагал, поэтому я решил поставить проприетарные драйвера. У меня стоит две видеокарты: Интел и NVidia geforce 820m(ноутбук). Поэтому я ещё хотел установить Bumblebee, который делает, чтобы видеокарты работали каждая, когда надо(Интел - просто работа, NVIDIA - игры). Потом, когда я перезапускал комп, у меня завис запуск на Started GNOME Display Manager. Я в линуксе вообще почти ничего не понимаю, поэтому поясните подробней плиз. Что мне делать: переустанавливать линукс, или ещё есть шанс всё вернуть?

Comment: Загрузитесь в _recovery mode_ и удалите драйвера?

Comment: А как именно ты их ставил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я несколько часов пробовал это сделать через recovery mode, в результате запустил, а там можно писать только русской раскладкой. Я ещё просидел час, и наконец нашёл способ писать с помощью Alt+NumPad. Так можно писать разные символы, в том числе и английские буквы. Помучался ещё пол часа и всё сделал. Как же всё сложно.

Comment: это при установке русская клавиатура была выбрана;
У меня вот так раскладка настраивается:
`setxkbmap -layout "us,ru" -variant ",phonetic" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"`